# How to extend firebase.User with a custom interface or pass custom values to a firebase collection in angularfire2?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Anyone knows a good way to insert some custom fields for the firebase.User, working with angularfire2? I am trying to do this (user here is being an object of firebase.User) after logged in, I pass the object and I also set my own property points

```
user.points = 1
db.collection('users').add(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)));
```

however the users object doesnt seem to take my custom fields/values (points) from my extended interface. Seems to be some serializing magic happening but I cant figure out what to do.

```
export interface User extends firebase.User {
    points?: number;
}
```

I expect my property of "points", being inserted to my firebase "users" collection as well as the other fields that being inserted. I mean you get a lot from this user object such as displayName but not my own stuff.

**Update: I use this workaround until I figure it out by using update on the firebase document.**

```
this.db.collection('users').add(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user))).then(u => u.update({points: 999}));
```

Comment: The text in the question doesn't match the code so it's a little unclear what's being asked. You are talking about a firebase User object which is not customizable. But your code is referring to data stored in a 'users' node, which is fully customizable. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: Basicly I just want custom properties added and for that I use my own interface extending firebase User. It works good until I try to insert the value to a collection. Then that value is not included to the collection. However, if I update ( as seen in the example ) I can update so that the custom prop is there.